# where to place logic in a server/client program

Tags: java, xml, sockets, text

I'm creating a simple text based multi player game in java.

I want a server program that is the central hub for all the communication between each client.

I'm wondering where should i place most of the logic in? client? server? should the server be simply a program that gives any information a client requests? or should the client program simply forward the commands from the user to the server and have the server decide what to do from there. ?

also, currently, both client and server sockets simply use ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream to send String "commands" back and forth between each other to determine what command the user is requesting. what is the preferred method of communication between a client and server? XML containing a sql-like syntax?

for example: 
lets say client A wants to attack client B. currently: i send a string from the client to the server that looks like this

"a attack b 1321"

1321 = location of client B in the database.

Comment: Any answer to this question will be a book on game design.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too broad for a definitive answer.  With that said, any calculations that a dishonest player with good hacking skills might subvert should be done on the server or at least checked there.  For example, a First Person Shooter would likely do all physics calculations on the client, and report the results of each shot to the server so that it could relay to the other clients.  The server doesn't have to check shots that the client says were misses, but it would need to do at least basic collision detection on shots that the client says were hits.

Decisions about whether a player is allowed to pick up a resource should be made on the server of course.

My basic rule of thumb is to try to keep the server free of unneeded calculations, but do those that require security or the overall instantaneous game state on the server.

Comment: in terms of the actual communication. would a simple bytestream back and forth be a good approach?

Comment: Bytes, text, JSON, XML - anything works as long as the client and server can encode and decode.  I have used each of those successfully. If you need to conserve bandwidth, don't use XML.